# Differences using $(). jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to ask what's the differences using with `$()` or without `$()`. In two cases actually it is working. Is there any differences i really not understand.

**jQuery**

```
var harf = $('<p>Hello there</p>').appendTo('body');
  $(harf).on('click', function(){
    alert('harf');
  });
```

//

```
var harf = $('<p>Hello there</p>').appendTo('body');
  harf.on('click', function(){
    alert('harf');
  });
```

Comment: `$(harf)` is not required since `harf` is a jQuery object... instead if you had a dom element reference or a selector then you need to use `$()` so that you can get a jQuery object back

Comment: `$(harf)` is like `var foo = Number(2)` compared to `var foo = 2`. There's no reason to convert it to a jQuery object as it's already one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is just totally useless. There's no point in embedding a jQuery object in a jQuery object.

Note that you could chain the calls, you don't really need that `harf` variable :

```
$('<p>Hello there</p>').on('click', function(){
    alert('harf');
}).appendTo('body');
```